# Как из Base64 получить обратно excel файл?

Tags: javascript, node.js

С интерфейса на сервер приходит файл-excel в base64.
Как обработать этот формат  и получить из него(base64) обратно файл в формате excel?

Comment: если это действительно base64, а не какой-нибудь `multipart/form-data` то попробуй `const buf = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');` и потом этот буфер пихнуть в файл

Comment: @nörbörnën а если multipart/form-data ?

Comment: тогда смотрите мой ответ на ваш предыдущий вопрос. а вообще все подробности можно узнать из консоли браузера